# Change Default Calendar of CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder

Tags: .net, internationalization, calendar, globalization, cultureinfo

I want to change the default calender of 'th-TH' culture from ThaiBuddhist to Gregorian and register it as a custom culture.

```
CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("th-TH", CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.AvailableCalendars = new Calendar[] { new GregorianCalendar()};
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();
```

Above segment does not change the default calendar.

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("th-TH");
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("th-TH", CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(cultureInfo);

cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();
```

This does not work either.

Comment: Sorry if you find this question offensive, but could you shed a bit of light on why you want to do that?

Comment: @Paweł Dyda We use SSRS Server side reporting and our client needs dates in Gregorian Calendar format while currency in 'Bhat'. The default calendar for 'th-TH' is Thai Buddhist.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it that way. Actually, there would be the easier way to override default calendar:

```
        CultureInfo thaiCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("th-TH");
        Console.Out.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(thaiCulture));
        DateTimeFormatInfo thaiDateTimeFormat = thaiCulture.DateTimeFormat;
        thaiDateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        Console.Out.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(thaiCulture));
```

That works for my console application. The only problem, it probably won't work for you. Why? I think that "SSRS Server Side Reporting" you mentioned run as a different process and I might be wrong, but I am pretty sure that you can override CultureInfo setting only for your current process. I don't think it could (and should) be done globally.

Also, I don't know specifics of reporting solution you are using, so it might be of no help, but couldn't you just pass already formatted date-time strings as parameters? That would be the way to solve it in i.e. Crystal Reports. The worst case scenario would be to write down formatted strings to database.

Comment: Actually using the method cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register() you can change the setting of that culture in the machine/server. I was able to change the 'Currency Symbol' using the above method that affected SSRS running on that server. But changing the Calendar doesnt work. As you said if this does not work we have to manually format the date. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are modifying an existing culture (replacement) you cannot remove calendars, but you can reorder them:

```
var carib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("th-TH",
                                            CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);
carib.AvailableCalendars = new Calendar[] { new GregorianCalendar(),
                                            new ThaiBuddhistCalendar() };
carib.Register();
```

Since it is a replacement culture, you won't see the effect until you start a new process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an existing Culture without removing it first:

```
CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.UnRegister("th-TH");
```

Comment: Already had a catch block to catch 'InvalidOperationException' and unregister the culture and register again. Didn't work.